# Getting HTML tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to scrap data from here: https://www.booli.se/annons/1887654

This is my code in python 2.7:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
page="https://www.booli.se/annons/2272818"
request = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml') 


Int[3]: soup.findAll('span', itemprop='name')[4].text.strip().encode('utf-8')

Out[3]:'3 rum, 67 m\xc2\xb2'


Int[4]:d=soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__value')

Out[4]: [<span class="property__base-info__value">\n\t\t\t17 mar
       2017\n\t\t</span>,
     <span class="property__base-info__value">\n\t\t\t2 850 000    
      kr\n\t\t\t<span class="property__base-info__sub-value">42 537    
      kr/m\xb2</span>\n</span>,
    <span class="property__base-info__value">4 921 kr/m\xe5n</span>,
    <span class="property__base-info__value">L\xe4genhet</span>,
    <span class="property__base-info__value">233 kr/m\xe5n</span>,
   <span class="property__base-info__value">3 tr</span>,
    <span class="property__base-info__value">1907 </span>]

  Int[5]: d[2].text.strip().encode('utf-8')
  Out[5]:'4 921 kr/m\xc3\xa5n'


 Int[6]: d[1].text.strip().encode('utf-8')
 Out[6]: '2 850 000 kr\n\t\t\t42 537 kr/m\xc2\xb2'
```

Now my questions:
Q1: In Out[3] ---> How can I separate 3 rum from 67 m\xc2\xb2?
Q2: In Out[3]---> How can I get rid of rum and m\xc2\xb2? I just want to save 3 as a number of rooms and 67 as area like: 
room   area
3      67

Q3: Out[5] Out[6] the same problem. I need to remove the texts and just save the values separately. Sorry that the webpage is in Swedish. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m\xc2\xb2` is printed because it can't figure out `m²` in UTF-8.

If you change `soup.findAll('span', itemprop='name')[4].text.strip().encode('utf-8')` to

`soup.findAll('span', itemprop='name')[4].text` it prints `3 rum, 67 m²`

If your confident that the source has a consistent format, and you only want the numeric values you could do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page="https://www.booli.se/annons/2272818"
request = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml')

info = {}
a = soup.findAll('span', itemprop='name')[4].text
a = [int(s) for s in a.split() if s.isdigit()]
info['Rooms'] = a[0]
info['Area'] = a[1]
temp = []
date = soup.findAll('span', class_='property__base-info__value')
for i in date:
    i = i.text.strip()
    temp.append(i)

temp[1] = temp[1].split('\n')[0]

info['Såld'] = temp[0]
info['Utropspris'] = temp[1]
info['Avgift'] = temp[2]
info['Bostadsty'] = temp[3]
info['Driftskostnad'] = temp[4]
info['Våning'] = temp[5]
info['Byggår'] = temp[6]
import pprint
pprint.pprint(info)
```

Comment: I now have a dict. Wonderful. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Mary just added some changes, might be more helfpul